# The $h-$th power of every element in a finite group of order $h$ is the identity element of the group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I work in population dynamics. I want to show somewhere in my work that the $h-$th power of every element in a finite group of order $h$ is the identity element of the group. I guess this is elementary result but it would be nice if somebody show me how to do it or where to find it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of every element of a group is a divisor of $h$ by [Lagrange's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)  So if $x$ is an element of your group of order $k$ then $h = k\cdot l$ for some $l.$ Hence we have

$$x^h = x^{k\cdot l} = (x^k)^l = (e)^l = e.$$

Comment: Can you provide a name of a book where I read this result for citation purpose.

Comment: @zizo abstract algebra by dummit and foote

Comment: @jim I can't open this book from google :-(.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to cite this theorem? One reason a theorem has a name is so that you can reference to it :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am master's student, I didn't know this.

Comment: I thought that a person must show where he find the result from.

Comment: Sure but usually if something has a name as known as this one then you don't cite the result. In a way the name by itself is the citation